# pod not restarting automatically when crashing after reaching memory limit

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running my elixir app on GKE

here is my deployment configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: production
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
        tier: backend
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsNonRoot: false
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myimage
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 3000m
            memory: 2000Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 2500m
            memory: 1000Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        args:
          - foreground
```

as you can see in the image, the pod reached its memory limit and crashed
[image: pod]

these are my last logs:

```
erl_child_setup closed

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Shutting down..

Node is not running!
```

and then my app is frozen, I get 502 when trying to request the app,

In order to restart I restart the pod (kubectl delete pod), and then it runs again,

my question is: why doesnt the pod restart automatically when reaches memory limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add probes that will check if your application is healthy.

Since you mentioned a `502`, I'm assuming this is a Phoenix application and you can add a health-check endpoint:

```
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /healthz
    port: 8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 3
  periodSeconds: 3
```

When this request stops receiving a `200`, then the Kubernetes Controller will restart your pod.

Comment: thanks! ill try it, do you know why it doesnt restart when reaching memory limit? isnt it a basic kubernetes feature?

Comment: It restricts allocating new memory, it doesn't restart the pod. Erlang supervisor will still be running, so Kubernetes won't even know it's dead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a memory or CPU trigger, as described in detail here: https://blog.powerupcloud.com/autoscaling-based-on-cpu-memory-in-kubernetes-part-ii-fe2e495bddd4

See https://medium.com/retailmenot-engineering/what-happens-when-a-kubernetes-pod-uses-too-much-memory-or-too-much-cpu-82165022f489 also.